C# Graph Auto Height from Maximum Value
I want to draw a graph, that shows integer values, and the maximum value sets the height for the rest of the entries. I'm using Paint and Rectangles. For example, if the overall graph height is 200px - the value of the highest record (for example 20) will be 200px. The value of a record 10 will be 100px. This code already sets autowidth correctly by dividing the graph width by the total number or records. I'm looking to apply a similar approach for the autoheight.
public void redrawGraph()
 {
     int rowCount = dataGridView1.Rows.Count;
     int dayBarWidth = grW / rowCount;
     int dayBarX = 0;
     int dayBarY = 0;

     int rowCountB = dataGridView1.Rows.Count;
     int[] coffeeCountArray = new int[rowCountB];

     for (int i = 0; i < rowCountB; i++)
     {
         if (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value != null)
         {
             coffeeCountArray[i] = Convert.ToInt16(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString());
         }
         else
         {
             coffeeCountArray[i] = 0;
         }
     }
    
     int maximum = coffeeCountArray.Max();  
     int dayDiv = maximum / grH;

     using (SolidBrush eraseBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Gray))

     {
         Graphics g = CreateGraphics();
         Rectangle erase = new Rectangle(grX, grY, grW, grH);
         g.FillRectangle(eraseBrush, erase);
     }
     using (SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Red))
     {
         Graphics g = CreateGraphics();

         for (int i =0; i < rowCount; i = i+1)
         {
             int numeric = Convert.ToInt16(numericUpDown1.Value);
             int thisRow = Convert.ToInt16(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString());

            dayBarY = grH - thisRow;
             Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(grX + dayBarX, grY+dayBarY, dayBarWidth, grH-dayBarY);
             g.FillRectangle(brush, rect);
             dayBarX = dayBarX + dayBarWidth;
            MessageBox.Show(dayBarY.ToString());
         } 
     }
 }

The first part of the code finds the highest record value in grid column and divides it by the graph height, but this is obviously the wrong way.

y_i = value_i / value_max * graph_height
